# Add google analytics tracking code to Dash App

Tags: python, google-analytics, plotly-dash

I am trying to add Google Analytics tracking to a Dash Web Application. I reviewed other similar questions and followed the suggestion, however, I am running into an issue.

In my `app.py`,

```
app = dash.Dash(....) 

 <html>
    <head>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXX"></script>
        <script>
            window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
            function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
            gtag('js', new Date());

            gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXX');
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

Error:

```
<html>
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I add GA tracking code in my Dash App?

Comment: This is probably not your actual code since you can simply not add just unquoted html in a .py file. Without any relation to plotly dash this is simply a Syntax Error since python only understands python code. So html need to be quoted as a string and returned by the flask apps routed methods [see standard flask hello world](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) or returned in the dash way by using the dash app.layout and dash components [see dash hello world](https://dash.plotly.com/layout).

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below worked for me kms!

```
app.html_layout = """<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
        <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-""></script>
    <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());

    gtag('config', 'G-458QGY6CQV');
    </script>
</head>
```

"""